# Is there any appropriate technique to look for a continuous, representative part of a time series dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, dataset, representative

I would like to know if there is any machine learning technique that could be used to solve the problem as follows. Imagine a time series dataset with several rows (observations) and many columns (variables). The whole time series data can be summarised by some statistical features. Is it possible to apply some learning method to discover a continuous part of the whole that is representative of the whole in terms of those statistical features?
This seems not to be a prediction problem nor a cluster problem because the mandatory condition is a continuous chunk of the dataset.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you say more about the statistical features you mentioned?